# How to conclude that function K(u,v) is constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I have a function of two variables which can be written as K(u,v)=K(f(u),g(v)). I'm aware that K=constant is equivalent to $\frac{\mbox{d} K}{\mbox{d} u}=\frac{\mbox{d} K}{\mbox{d} v}=0,$ but I'm not sure can I prove the same in the following way:
(I will write $K_u=\frac{\mbox{d} K}{\mbox{d} u}$ and so on.)

I assume $K_u=0,$ wich implies $K_{uv}=0$. From here, I obtain form of function $f$ (for wich holds $K_{uv}=0).$
Now, for that $f,$ I consider condition $K_v$=0 and get form of function $g$.
Are these $f$ and $g$ functions for which K(f(u),g(v))=const.? To me it looks so, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I'll add more details. Function K is of the form
$$K(u,v)=\frac{(f_1^2(u)+f_2^2(u)-1)g'(v)}{(f_1(u)\sin (g(v))+f_2(u)\cos(g_(v))-1)^2}.$$
Now I first assume $K$ is function of $v$ only, derive with respect to $u$ and obtain $K_u=0$. That expression is little complicated, so I derive it again now with respect to $v$ and analyze $K_{uv}=.$ From that, I get that functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are constants.
Can I now implement that functions in expression for $K$ and derive it with respect to $v,$ then assume $K_v=0$ to obtain form of function g for which the function $K$ will be constant?

Comment: What do you mean by "function $f$ for wich holds $K_{uv}=0$"?

Comment: From the expression of $K_{uv}$ (i.e. partial derivatives with respect to u, then v), which includes derivatives of $f$ and $g$, set to 0, I obtain the form of function $f$.

Comment: It remains unclear. Can you please expose your the details of your computation within your post? (and better write $K(u,v)=F(f(u),g(v))$).

Comment: I add little more details, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I doubt your "$K_{uv}=0\Rightarrow f_1,f_2$ are constant", because $g$ constant obviously implies $K_v=0$ hence $K_{vu}=0,$ without $f_1,f_2$ being constant.

Comment: There was a typo, in numerator stands derivative of function $g$ and assumption is that $K\neq 0,$ so $g$ is not constant.

Comment: Still, I can see no reason why "$K_{uv}=0⇒f_1,f_2$ are constant".